# Screen tearing on Intel graphics card with dual graphics cards on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: intel, tearing

I know the issue with screen tearing on an onboard Intel card has been asked before, not none of the solutions offered has worked for me.

I am using both of my graphics card with 2 screens connected to my Nvidia card and a television connected to my Intel card.
The 3 screen setup works fine, but there´s tearing on all screens.

The nvidia tearing is fixed by forcing full composition through the nvidia settings tool (though I have to do it again every time I reboot.

I cannot fix the Intel tearing though.

The solution that is usually offered is creating an intel conf file in the Xorg folder (ie. /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf or /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf), but doing that results in Xorg not working on boot.

Any other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: i recently fixed similar issue in my case, check my questiion, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368917/screen-tearing-on-intel-graphics-with-dual-monitor-setup-nvidia-and-intel/1370162#1370162